# Interesting Pandas dataframe problem: how to drop duplicates (inverse) over two columns - for each row with a common attribute?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, drop

After filtering out the inverse duplicates, I have to count how many actual duplicates there are. Here is my (working example) code, it's too slow though, for 90 000+ rows.. using iterrows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'id_x':[1,2,3,4,5,6],      
'ADDICTOID_x':['BFO:0000023', 'MF:0000016', 'BFO:0000023', 'MF:0000016', 'MF:0000016', 'ADDICTO:0000872'],     
'PMID':[34116904, 34116904, 34112174, 34112174, 34112174, 22429780],                  
'LABEL_x':['role', 'human being', 'role', 'human being', 'human being', 'FDA'],   
'id_y':[11,12,13,14,15,16],    
'ADDICTOID_y':['MF:0000016', 'BFO:0000023', 'MF:0000016', 'BFO:0000023', 'BFO:0000023', 'ADDICTO:0000904'],                
'LABEL_y':['human being', 'role', 'human being', 'role', 'role', '']}
dcp = pd.DataFrame(data)

dcp = dcp.drop(dcp[dcp.LABEL_x == dcp.LABEL_y].index)

for index, row in dcp.iterrows():  # THIS IS SLOW
        if ((dcp['ADDICTOID_x'] == row['ADDICTOID_y'])
            & (dcp['ADDICTOID_y'] == row['ADDICTOID_x'])
            & (dcp['PMID'] == row['PMID'])).any():  # Does the inverse of this row exist in the table?
            dcp.drop(index, inplace=True)

print("dcp after drop: ")
print(dcp)
```

I can't just use `dcp.duplicated(subset=['ADDICTOID_x', 'ADDICTOID_y'], keep='first')` because that removes ALL of the duplicates (there are many) and I only want to do them one by one, and the 'PMID' needs to match also. Similarly, `(dcp.ADDICTOID_x + dcp.ADDICTOID_y).isin(dcp.ADDICTOID_y + dcp.ADDICTOID_x) & (dcp.PMID == dcp.PMID)` finds rows with duplicates everywhere. Iterrows and test one by one is the only way I have found which works, but it's too slow. Anyone know of a solution to this?

After filtering for inverse duplicates, I count like so:
`data_chord_plot = dcp.groupby(['LABEL_x', 'LABEL_y'], as_index=False)[['PMID']].count() data_chord_plot.columns = ['source','target','value']`

EDIT: in this simple example, rows 1 and 3 are removed as they are inverse duplicates of rows 2 and 4.

EDIT: I need to eliminate the "mirror" image of rows with inverse duplicates over the two columns, but only one for each row with a duplicate. Some rows don't have a mirror image.

CORRECT OUTPUT FROM (SLOW) EXAMPLE:

id_x      ADDICTOID_x      PMID      LABEL_x  id_y      ADDICTOID_y LABEL_y

1     2       MF:0000016  34116904  human being    12      BFO:0000023    role

3     4       MF:0000016  34112174  human being    14      BFO:0000023    role

4     5       MF:0000016  34112174  human being    15      BFO:0000023    role

5     6  ADDICTO:0000872  22429780          FDA    16  ADDICTO:0000904

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a sorted tuple of `ADDICTOID_xy` and use `drop_duplicates` with the right subset:

```
dcp['ADDICTOID'] = dcp[['ADDICTOID_x', 'ADDICTOID_y']].apply(sorted, axis=1) \
                                                      .apply(tuple)

out = dcp.drop_duplicates(subset=['ADDICTOID', 'PMID'], keep='first')
```

```
>>> out
   id_x      ADDICTOID_x      PMID LABEL_x  id_y      ADDICTOID_y      LABEL_y                           ADDICTOID
0     1      BFO:0000023  34116904    role    11       MF:0000016  human being           (BFO:0000023, MF:0000016)
2     3      BFO:0000023  34112174    role    13       MF:0000016  human being           (BFO:0000023, MF:0000016)
5     6  ADDICTO:0000872  22429780     FDA    16  ADDICTO:0000904               (ADDICTO:0000872, ADDICTO:0000904)
```

Comment: Please see my edited question above, I think I phrased it wrong initially. Thanks for the answer, though. The dataset contains multiple rows with the same PMID - I only need to eliminate the "mirror" images of these, not more than one per row.

Comment: I have heard that itertuples is much faster than iterrows, working on a solution based on your answer. Wish me luck. Will accept this solution soon I think. Just can't use drop_duplicates, to drop all

Comment: For `PMID==34112174` how do you determine which is the mirror of other? The first  (id_x: 3) may as well be the mirror of one (id_x: 4) or the other (id_x: 5) except if you add the LABEL_x and LABEL_y in the comparison.

Comment: The brief is to "filter the table so that pairs are only represented in one direction, i.e. if we have both (role, addiction) and (addiction, role) for the same PMID we drop the second one" - I am afraid that my explanation wasn't describing this very well. Perhaps your answer is correct after all, and my example data is an incorrect representation of the dataset, or the original code (not mine) isn't doing the job right..

Comment: My suspicion was correct: your solution is indeed the one I needed (so badly) - just took a while to realise this. Marking this as accepted answer now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a shorter way, but I can think of merging the `df` with its inverese self, and then leaving only the lines without a previous match. So instead of your loop do:

```
dcp = dcp.merge(dcp[['id_x', 'PMID', 'ADDICTOID_x', 'ADDICTOID_y']].rename({'id_x': 'inv_id', 'ADDICTOID_x': 'inv_y', 'ADDICTOID_y': 'inv_x'}, axis=1), how='left')
dcp['was'] = (dcp['ADDICTOID_x'] == dcp['inv_x']) & (dcp['ADDICTOID_y'] == dcp['inv_y']) & (dcp['id_x'] > dcp['inv_id'])
dcp = dcp.sort_values(['id_x', 'was']).drop_duplicates('id_x', keep='last')
dcp = dcp.loc[~dcp['was'], 'id_x': 'LABEL_y']
```

Comment: Really appreciate you taking time to answer this. Unfortunately this solution drops row 5 also, which doesn't have an inverse duplicate (there are many such in the full dataset). I will study your answer and report back if I can make it work.

Comment: Why *shouldn't* it drop row 5? It's inverse to row 3 just like row 4 is.

Comment: Oh man that was my bad phrasing the question wrong then - I am trying to count duplicates. Some rows have an inverse, but I only want to eliminate one per row which has a "mirror image", the other needs to be counted. Sorry if I didn't get that across - the output from my code has the expected result. I will try to add that to the question

Comment: Your solution is correct, my bad. The one using tuple is the easiest, though. Thank you!